# What is the the method to use onComplete function to add Images to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have made a function to upload three images to firebase storage. I have been doing it with the help of a tutorial. Since the tutorial uses old version codes I am trying my maximum to change it to a newer version. In the tutorial, it uses **onComplete** method to get the task snapshot. But in the pub.dev docs it is said that these methods have been removed and their is an exception Like this(
***BREAKING: isCanceled, isComplete, isInProgress, isPaused and isSuccessful have now been removed. Instead, you should subscribe to the stream (for paused/progress/complete/error events) or the task Future for task completion/errors.***)

please tell what does this mean and how can I change my below code according to it.
there is an error showing in the place where I type **onComplete**

```
void validateAndUpload() async{
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      if (_image1 != null && _image2 != null && _image3 != null) {
        if (selectedSizes.isNotEmpty) {
          String imageUrl1;
          String imageUrl2;
          String imageUrl3;
          final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
          final String picture1 =
              '1${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg';
          UploadTask task1 = storage.ref().child(picture1).putFile(_image1);

          final String picture2 =
              '2${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg';
          UploadTask task2 = storage.ref().child(picture2).putFile(_image2);

          final String picture3 =
              '3${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}.jpg';
          UploadTask task3 = storage.ref().child(picture3).putFile(_image3);

        TaskSnapshot snapshot1 = await task1.onComplete.then((snapshot) => snapshot);
        TaskSnapshot snapshot2 = await task1.onComplete.then((snapshot) => snapshot);

        task3.onComplete.then((snapshot3) async{
             imageUrl1 = await snapshot1.ref.getDownloadURL();
             imageUrl2 = await snapshot2.ref.getDownloadURL();
             imageUrl3 = await snapshot3.ref.getDownloadURL();
        });


        } else {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Sizes cannot be Empty",
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white);
        }
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Images are not Filled",
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there! As the error says either you have to listen for the `UploadTask` streams or await for `UploadTask` to complete. For your case,

```
TaskSnapshot snapshot1 = await task1;
TaskSnapshot snapshot2 = await task2;
TaskSnapshot snapshot3 = await task3;

imageUrl1 = await snapshot1.ref.getDownloadURL();
imageUrl2 = await snapshot2.ref.getDownloadURL();
imageUrl3 = await snapshot3.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

For more ref - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#handling-tasks

Comment: I dont know the portion stream and kind...The code you given above..do I have to change with my code....So wheres the complete and error

Comment: instead of `TaskSnapshot snapshot1 = await task1.onComplete.then((snapshot) => snapshot);` this await `TaskSnapshot snapshot1 = await task1;` would work for you as per the doc! do the same for other images as well;

Comment: this will wait till the `UploadTask` complete; wrap these snippet within try and handle the exceptions;

Comment: how to get the getDownloadUrl...I need the snapshot

Comment: it returns the same `TaskSnapshot`; so your current code `await snapshot1.ref.getDownloadURL();` should work.

Comment: ok let me try and I will let you know..thanks for your time

Comment: Bro the url should be added to the variables after the completion of task3..In the previous code you can see the function is wirtte.

Comment: updated the snippet in my answer! if you are able to get `ref` form `TaskSnapshot` it will work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks it worked...```UploadTask task2 = storage.ref().child(picture2).putFile(_image2);
``` this code upload images to storage directly..What should I do to upload images to a folder in storage

Comment: you could append childs like storage.ref().child('images').child(picture1).putFile(_image1); I recommend you to go through this ref - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#references

Comment: if this solved your problem, accept this answer; so that, other viewers will get to know the correct answer!

Comment: OK, THIS WAS HELPFUL, I WILL ACCEPT IT