# Firebase Storage upload picture from gallery Flutter (No error)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I want to upload a picture choosen from gallery to Firestore Storage, this is my first time but I read docs and took a look on the internet, this is what I wrote (it works without errors but doing nothing on the storage).

Code below, I tested imgFromGallery and it works maybe the problem are Storage functions.

```
Future<File> imgFromGallery() async {
  try {
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    final PickedFile imageFile =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);

    //If there is no image selected, return.
    if (imageFile == null) return null;
    //File created.
    File tmpFile = File(imageFile.path);
    //it gives path to a directory - path_provider package.
    final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
//filename - returns last part after the separator - path package.
    final fileName = tmpFile.path.split('/').last;
//copy the file to the specified directory and return File instance.
    return tmpFile = await tmpFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

//Save file to Storage function

```
Future<void> setPicture(String pathStorage) async {
    try {
      final File file = await imgFromGallery();
      if (file == null) return;
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(pathStorage).putFile(file);
      return;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

P.S. : I would like to return the URL of the uploaded picture as return of "setPicture" but I still don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just few steps away!

```
TaskSnapshot task = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(pathStorage).putFile(file);
```

After successful upload, you will get `TaskSnapshot`. That has a reference member `ref`.

```
String image_url = await task.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

This `image_url` is the URL of the uploaded picture.

ref: [What is the the method to use onComplete function to add Images to Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948835/what-is-the-the-method-to-use-oncomplete-function-to-add-images-to-firebase-stor/65949689#65949689)

Comment: Nice thank you mate, but now my app crashes if I call the same function 2 times in a row. Do you know why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048537/ios-app-crashes-when-calling-this-function-2-times-in-a-row-firebase-storage-f this is the post, I will try to let it crash again and post the error